# How load an image from current window in the openGL code 

Tags: opengl

I have an openGL code rendering an image, and I need reload this image on code to reedit it, in a loop. How can I load this in the code?

```
glutInit (&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);     
 //
 glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

 glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
     glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
     glutCreateWindow("Model");


 //glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
     //glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
 //      
 glFrontFace(GL_CW);
 // 
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

 float near =  10000;
 float far = (131943+500000);

 int f = 80000;

 //glFrustum(-f, f, -f, f, near, far);

 //
glOrtho(-f, f, -f, f, near, far);

float s = 1;
glScalef(s,s,.125); 
glTranslated(0,0, -200000);


glutDisplayFunc(display);  
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMotionFunc(rotation);

glutMainLoop();
```

In Display() function a model is loaded, I need load this model rendered, and edit it again. Maybe  i need to load the pixels from window, because a loop will edit the model, till get the wanted shape

Answer (score 0):

You should render it to texture, and then work on the allocated texture buffer to render it on screen finally.

You could erase your code, because it doesn't give any valuable information, besides the fact you aren't using shaders. Which should also be considered, as it is the *proper* and the fastest way to do what you want.

Another good keyword for google might be "Multi-pass rendering".